# How to add or replace textfield input text to picker view text in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, uitextfield, uipickerview

[image]

I have a picker loaded with an array of strings, I want to change means appending or editing strings by typing in the text field and save in that array and display that changes in that picker view.Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want to add or replace, please provide some example. since either you cn replace text for selectedIndex of picker or add completely new entry in array.

Comment: I have a picker loaded with an array of strings, I want to change means appending or editing strings by typing in the text field and save in the array and display that changes in that picker view @Van

Comment: as per my understanding of your question , You can add text from textfield in delegate methods like textFieldShouldReturn or textfieldDidEndEditing method and add text of textfield to array and reload the picker at the same time.

Comment: yes, can you please tell some examples.

Comment: check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    addIntoArray(text: textField.text)
}

func addIntoArray(text: String?) {
    guard let text = text, text.count > 0 else {
        //for blannk or nil string
        return
    }

    listArray.append(text)
    //reload the picker
    picker.reloadAllComponents() //picker is the instanc of your pickerView
}   
}
```

try this

Comment: But I need to replace that object in the array with what I typed in the text field but it's adding one more object and it is saved temporarily, when navigating to another page and came back the same array displaying

Comment: you can check if the value is selected in picker then replace with text else add.

Comment: because you have added inputView as pickerView of textField, the keyboard isn't appearing. for this you would need to construct toolbar and add it as inputAccessoryView of textfield. and lets say on done button you can resignFirstResponder() for textfield.

Comment: also you can add different buttons like edit on toolbar and setting the inputView to nil for keyboard appearance and then on hit done you can replace or add the item accordingly